# How to Disable http user agent mozilla firefox only and enable all other browsers in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, firefox, mod-rewrite, user-agent

I am currently using this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/browsererror.html [R,L]
```

It is working good but what I want is to just disable Mozilla Firefox browser and enable all other browsers.
In my current .htaccess I am able to only enable Google Chrome and all other browsers are automatically disabled. is there any short .htaccess code so that I can only disable Mozilla Firefox browser and all other browsers will work fine ?
I just want to disable access from Firefox browser.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but what is the reason for your wanting this? If it's a HTML compatibility problem, there are *very* few these days that are unsolvable - if any.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/253419/htaccess-config-to-block-depending-on-browser-agent

Answer (score 1):

```
# matches regex for Firefox, and redirects to browsererror.html
# can add other browsers to block as ^.*(Firefox|other_browser).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Firefox).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/browsererror.html [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(Mozilla.*|Safari.*|Other.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]
```

Comment: It would help the poster if you could elaborate on *why* you proposed what you proposed, how it is supposed to function, etc.